# Has California released its certified presidential election results online?

Tags: united-states, election, presidential-election, voting, california

The media is reporting that [California has certified its results](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-12-04/biden-clinches-electoral-college-win-as-california-certifies) for the presidential election.

However, I can’t find the certified vote totals online. A quick check on the California Secretary of State’s website only shows [“Unofficial Election Results”](https://electionresults.sos.ca.gov/returns/president) with a note stating that “[r]esults will be certified by December 11, 2020”.

So, is there an official source stating that California has certified its results? If so, are the certified results for the presidential election available online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - or at least, not yet. Although many media sources are correctly reporting that California has certified its results, this is being confused with the final result certification. If we look at the [General Election Calendar](https://elections.cdn.sos.ca.gov/statewide-elections/2020-primary/section-8-general-calendar.pdf) posted on the California Secretary of State's website, we can see where the confusion is arising:

> **12/4/20**
> **115. STATEMENT OF RESULTS TO SECRETARY OF STATE**
> By this date, the county elections official shall send to the Secretary
> of State, in an electronic format, one complete copy
> of the general election returns for all candidates for United States
> Representative in Congress, State Senator, and Member of the State
> Assembly, and for all statewide ballot measures.
>
> **12/5/20**
> **116. CERTIFICATES OF ELECTION — PRESIDENTIAL ELECTORS**
> No later than this date, the Secretary of State shall analyze the votes given
> for Presidential Electors and certify to the Governor the names of the
> proper number of persons having the highest number of votes. The
> Secretary of State shall issue and transmit to each Presidential
> Elector a certificate of election.
>
> **12/11/20**
> **117. STATEMENT OF THE VOTE**
> Last day for the Secretary of State to prepare, certify, declare, and file a statement of the vote from the
> compiled election returns and post to the Secretary of State's
> website.

Note that these dates are deadlines, not exact dates. For example, by looking at the [county reporting status](https://electionresults.sos.ca.gov/returns/status) page we can see that this step (#115) was completed on the morning of December 3rd, rather than December 4th.

The certification reported by the media was, in fact, the certification of the result by the Secretary of State to the Governor (#116) and not the final certification of the statement of the vote (#117). The Secretary of State has until December 11th to publish the election returns online.